Using adb to move app and data to my tablet
I feel close to the solution... I have a Bluetooth grill temp probe from Thermopro. I have used it on my phone for a while and have a bunch of saved temp graphs of various dinners. Good information to review. Anyway - the app sort of shuts down if I get a call, so I want to move it to my tablet, but I'd like to copy all the good temp graphs and alarm settings from my phone too.
Using ADB, I made a copy of the apk from my phone and made a "backup" of the data.

First - I went to Google Play and found the proper apk name of the app. ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq

Using the ID, I found the full path to the app adb shell pm path cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq
package:/data/app/~~2bkB2UtzWXCnq6FqrD-qZw==/cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq-M73nd-LoCb2rEdiN3Pohiw==/base.apk 
package:/data/app/~~2bkB2UtzWXCnq6FqrD-qZw==/cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq-M73nd-LoCb2rEdiN3Pohiw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk 
package:/data/app/~~2bkB2UtzWXCnq6FqrD-qZw==/cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq-M73nd-LoCb2rEdiN3Pohiw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk


Then I made a backup on my laptop of the apk adb pull /data/app/~~2bkB2UtzWXCnq6FqrD-qZw==/cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq-M73nd-LoCb2rEdiN3Pohiw==/base.apk cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq.apk

Then I made a backup of the data adb backup - cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq -f cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq.ab

Then disconnecting my phone from ADB and USB, I connected my tablet to USB and enabled ADB.

I installed the apk adb install cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq.apk

Then I restored the backup data adb restore cn.com.adsmart.thermbbq.ab


The app works fine, but all the data I was hoping to preserve is not there.
I feel like there is one more twist I am missing. Any pointers are appreciated.

First the app has to allow backup at all. second adb backup and restore doesn't work anymore on Android 12+ for recent apps (that means all apps that had been updated in the last ~2 years).  Adb backups save no data

Thanks Robert.  I believe that might be so.  The backup file is very small.  47 bytes.  Is there a way to edit the manifest to allow backup at least for a moment?  Or maybe some way to find the files in the file system and copy them over and trick the app into having the saved data on the tablet?

Manifest editing wouldn't have an effect if the device is Android 12+ (that wouldn't work anyway as you would have to resign the app which makes it a different app, so your data would have to be deleted to install the resigned app). The best chance is to contact the company developing the the app and ask how you should proceed, may be there is a way to export your data and import them on the tablet using a functionality inside the app.

Robert - thanks for the reply.  I didn't know all that - but it makes sense.  I am thinking it is time I give up and learn to live without the data I can't transfer.  Thanks again
